# What is the function used to find a particular type of file (eg: *.cpp) in QT Programming?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt4

I need to find particular type of file on the PC. Can anyone give me the name of a function which I can use to find the system files ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want either the [QDir class](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html) and/or the [QFileInfo class](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html).  What method(s) you want to use on those objects depends on exactly what it is you want to do and how you want to do it.

Comment: It should check all the directories and provide the result.

Comment: Thanks Burr ! It should check all the directories and provide the result. I need to retrive those files . so is there any functions available ?

Comment: There is no such recursive function/method. You could use QDir to search for all files in certain directory and eventualy search all subdirectories. Remember that it will be time and resource consuming operation

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [setSearchPaths](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#setSearchPaths) method in QDir.  Depends on what you're looking for.

"Qt uses this search path to locate files with a known prefix."

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides a [QDirIterator](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdiriterator.html) which with the `QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks` and the`QDirIterator::Subdirectories` flags you can use to iterate over each item, if necessary getting `.fileInfo().completeSuffix()` or `.fileInfo().suffix()` (as desired) to check the extension type ("cpp" - no dot), and do with the file what you will.